# How to check error on load cog with discord rewrite.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to do a robust error checking with discord rewrite.py for my cog loading function.

Here is my code :

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, extension):
   bot.load_extension(f"module.{extension}")


@load.error
async def load_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
        await ctx.channel.send("You must be the owner to use this command.")
        print(error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.channel.send("You must tell me which extension to load")
        print(error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded):
        await ctx.channel.send("Extension Already loaded")
        print(error)
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("An error as occured, please contact the bot owner")
        print(error)

bot.run("NeverWriteYourTokenOnInternet")
```

I have some wierd interaction with my error handler,
the not owner work flawlessly so i guess i have the right syntax.

The missing required argument doesn't work quit well, although it is triggering this error, it also trigger the else statement. I have two error messages (which is bothering) my best guess is that the function raise two exceptions but i couldn't find anything on the API references.

The third one is even wierder, i checked the API references multiple times and the load_extension raise the ExtensionAlreadyLoaded exception. But it only trigger the global error, the printed error is the following. `Command raised an exception: ExtensionAlreadyLoaded: Extension 'module.tts' is already loaded.`

I don't need to say i have the same problem with the unloading function.

If anyone know what is happening, it would be a lof helpful.

Comment: Try to use `if / elif / elif [...]` and your `else` statement as a last way out at the end.

Comment: It work perfectly, i though the exception hierarchy would be enough.
It only correct the first bug, not the second one

Answer (score 1):

`commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded` doesn't inherit from `commands.CommandError`, that means that you do not handle it in the error handler, simply with a try-except block

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    try:
       bot.load_extension(f"module.{extension}")
    except commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded:
        await ctx.channel.send("Extension Already loaded")
```

Comment: In the documentation i could not find ```commands.MissingRequiredArgument``` inheriting from ```commands.CheckFailure```
Could you please show me where you find any references ?

Comment: *PS: Sorry, it's not `commands.CheckFailure` but `commands.CommandError`*. It's not in the docs, take a look at the source code: [`commands.MissingRequiredArgument`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/errors.py#L138) inherits from [`commands.UserInputError`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/errors.py#L119) which inherits from [`commands.CommandError`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/errors.py#L85)

Comment: So it need to inherit from ```commands.CommandError```
[API references](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html) I mainly use this webpage and it is referenced, i just didn't know it needed to inherited from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    try:
        bot.load_extension(f"module.{extension}")
        await ctx.send(f"{extension} loaded successfully".)
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(str(e))
```

This will send error message if any error has occured like `syntax`, `unexpected indent`, `extension already loaded` and other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for you help, it work flawlessly now.

If you are trying to do what i did here is how.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, extension):
   try:
      bot.load_extension(f"module.{extension}")
   except commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded:
      await ctx.channel.send("This extension is already loaded")
   except commands.ExtensionNotFound:
      await ctx.channel.send("I could not find the extension you tried to load")
   except commands.ExtensionFailed:
      await ctx.channel.send("I failed to load the extension !")
   except Exception as e:
      await ctx.send("An unexpected error as occured")
      print(e)

@load.error
async def load_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
      await ctx.channel.send("You must be the owner to use this command")
   elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
      await ctx.channel.send("You must tell me which extension to load")
   else:
      await ctx.channel.send("An error as occured, please contact the bot owner")
      print(error)
```

It should handle most error on a extension load.
The first exception cannot be part of the load_error function since they don't inherit from `commands.CommandError`, they have to be handled appart.